# Функции без скобок в PHP

Tags: php

В PHP функции вызываются как `func('data');`
Но, к примеру, функция `include` может вызываться как `include('data')` и как `include 'data';`

Как сделать у себя такую же функцию?

Answer (score 7):

...отсутствуют вообще. Есть языковые конструкции, которые со скобками ошибочно воспринимаются как функции, например,

```
print
echo
include
require
eval...
```

Напишите свой PHP с блэкджеком и функциями без скобок.

Изврат. Нормальным людям дальше не читать!!!

Кратко, создаем что-то типа:

```
function myPHPconverter($file){
  preg_match_all('/function\s+([a-zA-Z_]+)/',file_get_contents($file),$all_my_functions);
  //Работа сс ключевыми словами функций
}
```

После чего эта функция для каждой вашей псевдофункции создает нормальную и через 
call_user_func вызывает.

Матан тут в том, что надо правильно распарсить все, что идет между ключевиком функции и ИСТИННОЙ точкой_с_запятой. Это не очень просто.
Фактически, вы создаете интерпретатор на интерпретаторе. Мьсьё извращенец только если.

Итог: вы пишете файл, сохраняете его как myPHP, потом вместо инклюда вызываете свой конвертер.

Comment: А по другому никак?)

Comment: А вам, собственно, зачем? =)

Есть один способ. Но он непростой и требует знания "матана".

Comment: Требуют и всё тут... 2 скобки не хотят =(

Comment: Кто требует и кто не хочет две скобки? Объясните подробнее, может вы вообще не о том спрашиваете.

Comment: '/function\s*\'[a-z_]+\'/'i вроде так, не?

Comment: нет. Название функции без кавычек задается